# How do I give individual UV maps to textures

Tags: texturing, uv

I have a texture that is scaled up to about 50x or so, and want to texture paint a B&W factor onto it so  I can another texture. However, the texture paint is inheriting the same uv map and is tiling the edits, nearly crashing blender every time. How do I have individual texture maps, and have it so that each texture uses the right one? I dont want to use mapping nodes because the scaling isn't to a discreet value and the model is to complex to eyeball it. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Sorry if this is a bad question.

Comment: There's an _Input > UV Map_  shader node that lets you select separate UV maps for different textures in a shader tree.

Comment: Wow...did not expect the answer to be that simple...But thank you anyway :D